# "wrong-type-argument stringp nil" error on symbol completion using semantic

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-semantic

When using 'senator-complete-symbol' on C++ source file, some times it works but most of the time I ended up with the error "wrong-type-argument stringp nil,  compare-strings("Ins" 0 nil nil 0 3 nil)". I have no idea why semantic is working so inconsistently. I've tried countless of time exiting emacs, deleting the semanticdb directory and reentering emacs to force the semanticdb being recreated but like I said, it sometimes works with no reason but most of the time it doesn't work.

The version of CEDET I'm using is from:

```
bzr checkout bzr://cedet.bzr.sourceforge.net/bzrroot/cedet/code/trunk cedet
```

I've tried v1.0 but that gave me compilation error while the version bundled in Emacs 23.2 doesn't have this feature at all. Could anybody give me any idea how I can make this work? Are there better tools I can use in emacs for code completion and code browsing? I'm a little frustrated because I'm approaching deadline and CEDET has wasted me a lot of time, I don't know why CEDET seems to be so problematic.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: This is a bug in the CEDET develop version and have been fixed in the latest version. So far I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, I had similar problems that went away after I re-compiled ecb and cedet for the particular version of Emacs I was using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this was my first post here and I didn't even expect to get any reply as fast as this, thanks again. I've compiled the package for so many times, sometimes it worked after recompiling but that never lasted long, it worked only for awhile.

Comment: The other thing to try is setting debug-on-error to t and finding out what is happening when it occurs.  That info will also help any bug report (as @pokita suggested).

Comment: I have done that already, it is this function call that causes the error:'compare-strings("Ins" 0 nil nil 0 3 nil)', where "Ins" was the first three letter of the symbol I wanted to complete.

Comment: I'm stumped, but here's another long shot idea:  Have you checked to make sure you don't have other fragments of either CEDET or ECB in your emacs lisp paths.  I sort of remember an issue where I had two different ECB versions.  One was installed when I installed emacs, and another was manually downloaded and installed.

Comment: Actually I had similar mismatching problem with EDE when I put (global-ede-mode t) before loading the external cedet package. Most of the time EDE just complains about unknown syntax, fortunately there had been once that emacs reported "cedet 1.0 had been loaded already" when it tried to load the external cedet. From there I realized that the 'built-in' cedet had been loaded by (global-ede-mode t) already.
It is lucky when emacs could detect this kind of mismatch but how can I absolutely sure there is no such mismatch at all?

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be a bug, please report the error on the CEDET mailing-list with a short recipe how to reproduce this. All I can tell you now is to not use senator but one of the semantic-ia functions for completion, like semantic-ia-complete-symbol, semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu or semantic-ia-complete-tip.

Comment: I'm going to report to the mailing-list tonight.

Comment: I'm going to report to the mailing-list tonight. Thanks for your advice, yes, I also noticed that the '-ia' group of functions are much better, however, unfortunately, after adopted alexott's cedet configuration file, nothing works now. Whatever I did, I got that same error.